# How can I add an IBAction for a button in a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, ibaction

I am trying to drag my buttons into the implementation but there is no prompt to create an IBAction. I had the ability to do that when the view was a class `ViewController` then I switched it to `UIViewController` I cannot add IBAction now. I was having issues with the programmatic segue when it was `ViewController`. The **Stop Alerting** button I had in there now throws errors that is why I am now trying to create a new button.

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**
I tried two ways. First adding an interface and method to the existing method and header files. That did nothing. Then I tried adding them to new method and header files and that did nothing either.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface alertingView : UIViewController

@end
```

and method

```
#import "alertingView.h"

@implementation alertingView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"test alertingView");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

When this happen it is because **the class set on your XIB** (owner of the button) **is not the same** of the class where your are trying to release the mouse.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will try creating an implementation for the uiview controller then.